# Set time gap/timer between 'foreach controller' requests in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Set time gap/timer between 'foreach controller' requests.

We have a below scenario:
Login single user>click question multiple times

To achieve above scenario in Jmeter used below Test Plan:

`ThreadGroup - 1 user, 1 ramp up period, 1 loop`

`-HTTP request to login`

`-Questionslist - RegExp to get list of questions with -1`

`-ForEach Controller - 100 times loop count`

`--HTTP request`

When 'Timer' is set under 'ForEach controller' doesn't actually considered this timer value (ex: 2000 milliseconds)

Please guide how to have time gap between 'ForEach controller' http request.

Comment: can you show the timer you added?

Comment: Thanks for inputs, however not able to test and share things since our app is currently down, will check once again and update.

Answer (score 0):

Actually [Constant Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) should work however you will not see this delay anywhere as by default the duration of [PreProcessors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#preprocessors), [Post-Processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and [Timers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) is not included into Sampler time.

You could put your HTTP Request and the Timer under [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller) and configure it to:

- Generate Parent Sample
- Include duration of timer and pre-post processors in generated sample

This way you will get Timer time (2 seconds) added to your Sample Result.

---

However above approach is on **per-user** basis, it means that each virtual user will have a 2-second delay between HTTP Request. If you would like to have 2 seconds of absolutely idle time, i.e. when no requests are being made at all you can add a [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) sampler after HTTP Request sampler and configure it to produce a 2000 ms delay. Also put [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) as a child of the Test Action sampler and set `Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by` to be equal to the number of virtual users in [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) - this way Test Action sampler will act as a [rendezvous point](http://sqa.fyicenter.com/FAQ/LoadRunner/What_is_a_rendezvous_point_.html) and all the virtual users will "meet" there to "sleep" together for 2 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for inputs and guidance, however not able to test and share things since our app is currently down, will check once again and update.